# passing row from foreach of range, ByRef Argument type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have fixed my problem by doing things another way (see the end). But I am curious as to how to pass a row range to a sub. The original problem...

I get a ByRef Argument type mismatch in the following Excel 2007 VBA code.
Perhaps the row extracted from the foreach of the ranges isn't itself a range?

```
Sub colorcells()
For Each bgr In Worksheets("1k sort").Range("AO2:AQ1001").Rows
  colorrow bgr
Next bgr
For Each bgr In Worksheets("1k sort").Range("as2:au1001").Rows
  colorrow bgr
Next bgr
For Each bgr In Worksheets("1k sort").Range("aw2:ay1001").Rows
  colorrow bgr
Next bgr
End Sub

Sub colorrow(ByRef gbrrow As Range)
  red = gbrrow.Cells(, 3).Value
  blue = gbrrow.Cells(, 2).Value
  green = gbrrow.Cells(, 1).Value
  gbrrow.Interior.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
  red = (128 + red) Mod 256
  blue = (128 + blue) Mod 256
  green = (128 + green) Mod 256
  gbrrow.Font.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
End Sub
```

I'm building 1000 entry palette tables for the Kalles Fraktaler fractal program using excel spreadsheets. After sorting each bit slice of RGB values (top bits then 2nd , 3rd etc) I'd like to see the colours in the spreadsheet by colouring the cell backgrounds. That made the text unreadable so I added the code to also set the font colour to the complement of the background colour. Not wanting to have 8 lines of the same code in each for next loop I thought I'd create a subroutine. Hmm... not so simple.

As a test I removed the sub call and inlined the code into the three for each loops. eg.

```
Sub colorcells()
For Each bgr In Worksheets("1k sort").Range("AO2:AQ1001").Rows
  red = bgr.Cells(, 3).Value
  blue = bgr.Cells(, 2).Value
  green = bgr.Cells(, 1).Value
  bgr.Interior.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
  red = (128 + red) Mod 256
  blue = (128 + blue) Mod 256
  green = (128 + green) Mod 256
  bgr.Font.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
Next bgr
For Each bgr In Worksheets("1k sort").Range("as2:au1001").Rows
  red = bgr.Cells(, 3).Value
  blue = bgr.Cells(, 2).Value
  green = bgr.Cells(, 1).Value
  bgr.Interior.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
  red = (128 + red) Mod 256
  blue = (128 + blue) Mod 256
  green = (128 + green) Mod 256
  bgr.Font.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
Next bgr
For Each bgr In Worksheets("1k sort").Range("aw2:ay1001").Rows
  red = bgr.Cells(, 3).Value
  blue = bgr.Cells(, 2).Value
  green = bgr.Cells(, 1).Value
  bgr.Interior.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
  red = (128 + red) Mod 256
  blue = (128 + blue) Mod 256
  green = (128 + green) Mod 256
  bgr.Font.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
Next bgr
End Sub
```

That produced some weirdness. All the columns of the ranges and those in between got widened. My clear colours subroutine left many font colours at the bottom of the ranges untouched. The last two rows of the range got their alignment changed to centred.
I think perhaps trying to set 3000 font colours is something Excel is unprepared for. I'll leave the font colouring out for now.

So the fix is to pass the entire range, the for each loops passing each row are unnecessary

```
Sub colorcells()
  With Worksheets("1k sort")
    colorrange .Range("AO2:AQ1001")
    colorrange .Range("as2:au1001")
    colorrange .Range("aw2:ay1001")
  End With
End Sub

  Sub colorrange(ByRef gbrrng As Range)
    For Each gbr In gbrrng.Rows
      red = gbr.Cells(, 3).Value
      blue = gbr.Cells(, 2).Value
      green = gbr.Cells(, 1).Value
      gbr.Interior.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
'    red = (128 + red) Mod 256
'    blue = (128 + blue) Mod 256
'    green = (128 + green) Mod 256
'    gbr.Font.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
    Next gbr
  End Sub

Sub clearcolors()
  With Worksheets("1k sort")
    clearrangecolor .Range("AO2:AQ1001")
    clearrangecolor .Range("as2:au1001")
    clearrangecolor .Range("aw2:ay1001")
  End With
End Sub

Sub clearrangecolor(ByRef gbrrng As Range)
  gbrrng.Font.Color = xlcolorautomatic
  gbrrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End Sub
```

Just uncommented and testing the font colouring. Mostly working, it still leaves most of the last two rows of the ranges centre aligned. I'll leave it commented, the point is a quick check that the colour sorting didn't result in some hideous striping before I write the Kalles fraktaler palette file. I don't really need to read the rgb values, just see the colors.

Thank you for any help,

Jeremy Thomson

Comment: I don't even see any reason to be passing your vars `ByRef`. You are not attempting to send updated arguments back to the caller.

Comment: You can combine the ranges like this `....Range("AO2:AQ1001","as2:au1001","aw2:ay1001").Rows`

Answer (score 1):

`colorrow()` is expecting a Range object as a parameter.  By default `bgr` is a Variant data type because you never declared it as a Range.  This causes the compiler to throw an ByRef Type Mismatch Error.

```
Sub colorcells()
    Dim bgr As Range
    For Each bgr In Worksheets("1k sort").Range("AO2:AQ1001").Rows
        colorrow bgr
    Next bgr
    For Each bgr In Worksheets("1k sort").Range("as2:au1001").Rows
        colorrow bgr
    Next bgr
    For Each bgr In Worksheets("1k sort").Range("aw2:ay1001").Rows
        colorrow bgr
    Next bgr
End Sub

Sub colorrow(ByRef gbrrow As Range)
    red = gbrrow.Cells(, 3).Value
    blue = gbrrow.Cells(, 2).Value
    green = gbrrow.Cells(, 1).Value
    gbrrow.Interior.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
    red = (128 + red) Mod 256
    blue = (128 + blue) Mod 256
    green = (128 + green) Mod 256
    gbrrow.Font.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think .rows returns a range reference, you can look at the bgr in the locals window before the first call to see what it is.  You should dim it explicitly as a range before you use it, anyway.

If you were to use:

For each bgr in (ws).range(AO2:AO502).cells

Then you could change the called routine to rereference gbrow to get the other values ie 
Set gbrow =gbrow.resize(1,3)

Comment: Perhaps even better, just pass the entire range to the sub, read it into an array, then loop through the array to do your calcs

Comment: `Rows` is a range object.  When in doubt you can use `TypeName()`. For example: Type `?TypeName( Range("AO2:AO502").Rows )` in the Immediate Window.